# Single aura:valueChange handler without declaring aura:handler markup for each tracked attribute

Tags: lightning

I have a form with 9 attributes inside a component. These are attributes of a questionnaire. A user cannot leave the form if the form is already "dirty", or changes have been made to the form. When I say "changes made", I mean one of the 9 attributes have changed their values.

Right now I declare 9 aura:valueChange handlers for each attribute. What I'm looking for is a way to refrain from adding so many `aura:handler` tags in the `.cmp`, and instead add handlers dynamically via the controller on `init`